# How to Consume POST Rest API on Django Web? want to consume API of User registration in django and here is the code which i have done

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

In Views.py
this the code in view.py
def Save(request):

```
      if request.method == "POST":
            user=request.POST
            email=user.get("email")
            password=user.get("password")
            print "password",password
            display_name= request.POST.get('displayname')
            hometown = request.POST.get('hometown')
            gender = request.POST.get('radios')
            occupation= request.POST.get('occupation')
            services.post_register(email,password,display_name,gender)
```

in Service.py code is-
service.py

```
def post_register(email,password,display_name,gender):
    postdata={'email':email,'password':password,'display_name':display_name,'gender':gender,'}

    response = requests.post('http://www.example.com/rest-auth/users/1/',
                    data=json.dumps(postdata))
```

afer running this i am getting response 415. thank you

Comment: You've got a trailing apostrophe before your closing brace on the `postdata=...` line. Is this an accident in copying or an actual error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

415 error code means that the media type is not supported. I think you can simply replace the `json.dumps(postdata)` by `postdata`. Looking at the `requests` library you don't need it:

```
r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply, whenever i do like this i got error 500(internal server error) i did the same as u suggested.

Comment: Can you paste the full Stacktrace?

Comment: thanks a lot. your help worked, i was facing authentication error